# How to develop subsumption architecture using two Arduinos?

Tags: arduino

I know what subsumption architecture is, and I'm sure I should have two different hardware modules (Arduinos) taking responsibility for low level computational tasks.

Now my problem is I have an two Arduinos and I want Arduino A to subsume or inhibit a signal from Arduino B . Does anyone have any idea how this is done? As I can wire Arduino A to send a signal to Arduino B but I'm unsure how to subsume or inhibit the signal? I want to use the Arduino Interrupt pin and functionality; instead of simply saying if the input A signal is < something, do something. As Modules should be activated in their own right, right?

Comment: You are making many choices in your system that are not typical. That is ok, but you should describe the sensing and actuation portions of your system to get a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would wire the two such that if A is subsuming a function of B such that the pin stays low as long as the inhibition lasts. Either B could check the state of this pin or it could have an interrupt set to signal when the pin goes low.

For B, if the action was already happening, a short interrupt routine could stop the action. If the action was about to begin then it could check the state of the pin to see if it should being.

I would put all the logic on A and have B hooked up to the sensors and actutors. Every time something changed it would communicate with A and A would handle all the logic. Just my thoughts. If the logic were difficult, I would use a Raspberry Pi instead of Arduino A.

Comment: thanks guys ....but I realised how stupid I was being...by mid dissertation  time...

All you have to do is have inputs to both Arduinos, and an interupt line to both Arduinos, and an input line from Arduino A to B, then define the interrupt actuator or parameter...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article (videos included) about how to navigate a maze using subsumption architecture and arduino.

http://www.codingnaked.com/post/arduino-powered-robot-solves-a-maze-using-subsumption-architecture-in-c/

Comment: thanks but again I realised how to build it in the end - but here is another question if both Arduinos are servers - how could I get their buses accessible or connected?  if they are not connected to routers and I didn't have their external IP...how would i get them networked?

as passing data via lines would be true to listening for bus data...